# Custom Gallery plugin uploading to different dir, and post to page

Tags: plugins, media, gallery, directory

I am trying to create a custom gallery plugin for my wp theme. So far I have found snippets on how to include the media uploader to my plugin, and also change my upload directory only for this plugin.

However Im having some trouble combining everything.

Basically I want to upload multiple images, save them to a custom dir, and post images to a specific page.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you share your code and give details of any research you have done? What specific issues are you having?

Comment: Thank for replying @Mat I haven't yet had the time to write the code as I'm watching a step by step tutorial to try to actually understand it. The end result will be uploading an image and dynamically update the html of the plugin admin page with that image. What I cant seem to find is how to post that image to a specific page.

Comment: Also I would like to save these images uploaded from this plugin page only to a different upload directory. I'm not sure I'm making any sense here...Im new to this.